# Why is the first data on highcharts not like the others

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Why the first and last category shows only 3 pieces of data?
Normally there must be five.
The others seem normal.You can see the result from the picture.when I don't use height property it gives the same result

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98uaeymL/1/)

[ımage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfEYS.png)

```
 chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      height: ((data.categories.length ) * 200) + 'px',
  },

  title: {
      text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
      categories: data.categories,
      title: {
          text: null
      }
  },
  yAxis: {

      title: {
          text: 'Puan',
          align: 'high'
      },
      labels: {
          overflow: 'justify'
      }
  },
  legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      x: -40,
      y: 80,
      floating: true,
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
      shadow: true
  },
  plotOptions: {

        bar: {

            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
  credits: {
      enabled: false
  },
  series: data.drivers
```

Comment: Sorry but it is impossible to help you from this limited information. Have you tried adding another result into the first chart to see if the problem is due to the chart having less results? **Edit:** Thank you for updating your question with the relevant source code. I will have a read to see if I can find the problem. [

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the pointPlacement to 0 in your data in jsfiddle for all the series and it is working fine again. Setting it to on creates a padding which hides  part of the chart. Read up on it [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointPlacement).